# Is there a way to make 365 safelinks not show the full unreadable link?

Tags: email, outlook, office365, html-email, safelinks

Safelinks in Outlook 365 are horrendous. Is there a reason why they put the full link into the text body?

I mean, is there a reason they aren't like this:

```
<html>
    <head />
    <body>
        <a href="https://aus01.safelinks.protection.outlook.com/">https://www.originallink.com/</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

so you can parse the original link whilst still being 'protected'? Is there a option to display them like this, rather than just turning off Safelinks altogether?

Answer (score 0):

You can develop VBA macro or COM add-in where you could replace hyperlinks with your own format. For that you need to handle the `NewMailEx` event of the Outlook `Application` class which is fired for every received item that is processed by Microsoft Outlook. The item can be one of several different item types, for example, `MailItem`, `MeetingItem`, or `SharingItem`. The `EntryIDsCollection` string contains the Entry ID that corresponds to that item.

The `NewMailEx` event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. Use the Entry ID returned in the `EntryIDCollection` string to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item.

In the event handle you have access to the `HTMLBody` property where you can find all hyperlinks and do the required replacements.